# Washer/dryer in the garage

Tags: laundry

Florida home: I'm wanting to relocate my washer and dryer to the garage. It is a gas dryer.

Question: Do I need to elevate both units off the garage floor? ( It is post 2003.)

Comment: Is there a reason you think you need to raise them off the floor?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know Florida but in Oregon you would , I believe if your water heater Is elevated your dryer would be covered by the same requirements because of possible flammable fumes from the garage, when the gas burner starts up. I recently raised my washer and dryer (both front loaders) 13-14” off the ground because of washer issues and my wife loves the height. 
I would raise it even if not code after doing it.